# Parsing Google Books JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm relatively new to Android and never used any parsers before I'm trying to parse the following [Json](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780007128457) from Google books api, extracting the title of the book and author. This is the code so far:

```
public void parseJson(String stringFromInputStream)
    {
        String strParsed = null;
        try 
        {
            JSONobject jsonObject= new JSONObject(stringFromInputStream);
```

`JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
            strParsed = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("volumeinfo").toString();
        }`

What I want to do in the above code is to loop through the JSON array which is "items" and get "volumeinfo" then from there I hope to extract title and author but I do not know how to continue. So I hope someone could point me to the right direction and correct me because the above are most likely incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Volumeinfo isn't a string, don't get it as one

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject volumeInfo = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
    String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
    JSONArray authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
    for(int j =0; j< authors.length(); j++){
        String author = authors.getString(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code but I'm getting a JSONException saying "No value for volumeinfo". I looked around and used [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to view the JSON and I can see that volumeinfo is enclosed within "0" but even after modifying the code I seem to still be getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, it should be volumeInfo.  I forgot to capitalize the I

Comment: Wow I had been looking at the Json file and I didn't notice the lower case i was meant to be an upper case. Thanks it fully works now!